# Can TFS2010 be set up locally in order to use Test Manager but still tie into work items, bugs, & source code residing in a remote TFS2008 instance?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

We currently use TFS2008 for our source control, bug tracking, and tasks. The TFS2008 server is located in a remote data center.  Locally, we have Visual Studio 2010 installed on the developer's machines. Is there a way to install TFS2010 so that we can run Test Manager but still tie into the work items and source code on the remote 2008 instance/database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and No.

First the No - You cant connect work items from two instances of TFS. You cant even connect between two team collections on the same sharepoint server. If you do not realy need this or you can upgrade your TFS 2008 to 2010 then stop reading.

**Advanced only**

The Yes - If you install a local TFS 2010 instance you can setup a sync between the work items and source control of the TFS 2008 box. Note that this will be hard as the TFS 2008 probably uses the MSF Agile 4.2 template and you would have the MSF Agive 5.0 template on your local TFS 2010. You will need to set up mappings between the Work Item types and a zero mapping for the Work item types that do not exist on the 2008 box (Test Case being one)

To do this you use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) which comes with a TFStoTFS Migration tool out of the box, but you will need to setup the mappings. If you had two identical TFS boxes this is not required, but you need to be able to sync both Work Items and Source Control to keep the Attachments and Links in place.

You then check in and associate with work items to your local TFS 2010 which will then sync that change to the remote TFS 2008 box.

Only use this if there are no checkins to the remote box! You will have to resolve conflicts on the server you use to sync if you do just as if you were checking in.